# Create login page with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, login-page

Following numerous inconclusive research so I decided me to ask for help.

I have class project achieving a login page login / pwd , nothing complicated far. The problem? Having to work with a SQL Server database. And then, well you look on the net and you find nothing , or almost nothing.

I managed to set up the connection to the database with this code (in index.php):

```
    $db = new connectionBdd();

    $db->connectSqlServer('ServerXXXX','NomdeTable', 'User', >'Mdp');
```

Then what? How do I establish a connection with login/password?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What library is the `connectionBdd` from?

Comment: Hello Halfer and thanks for the traduction and editing of my post.

It's a ODBC connection via SQL Server Drivers, it's what you want ?

Comment: Right. I can't find that library on the web, so assume it is custom-built. What problem are you having? Does your code create a connection? What are the four parameters you have supplied? What happens when you run this?

Comment: This code it's exact.
The problem is ""how make the login / password page for the user" , because when I seek, in google for example, I find what I need but all with MySQL and not with SQL Server ! You understand my problem ? 
The teacher imposed the usage of SQL Server .. So it's the same ? Or not ? Because I think many fonction of MY SQL doesn't exist for SQL Server .. 
Anyway , thank you for your very quick answers.

Comment: You don't make a page in sql server or any other database. The page resides on the web server and communicates with sql server to authenticate a user. Your database connection is likely going to use a consistent username and password for the website.

Comment: Right, so you want a login system. How to do that is largely independent of the database you are connecting to - if you can find a way to do it through the PDO library, then just swap the MySQL connection details for [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249690/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-through-php) and it will probably work (there are some SQL dialect differences, but they are relatively minor). See my profile for how to make a login system with PHP - it uses SQLite, but I think it would work on other databases just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the answer after a long time !

I have resolve the problem. 
If this can help, here is my code :

```
 <?php    
session_start();

    $serverName = "A106MVP19\SQLEXPRESS";   
    $uid = "sa";     
    $pwd = "root";    
    $databaseName = "FormaSport";   

    $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                              
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);   

    /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
    if( $conn === false ) 
    {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   
?>
```

Thx for our answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PDO?

All you need is sql server client installed and the correct mssql dll for your php version and then use something like this:

$conn = new PDO('sqlserver:host=HOST;port=PORT;dbname=DATABASE','USER','PASSWORD');

$result = $conn->query('select * from table');
print_r($result->fetchAll())