# How to connect to SQL Server 2012 to a website

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

This is my first question, I'm new here at Stackoverflow. I am just wondering if anyone could guide me on how to connect a game website remotely to a SQL Server database on a local server or at a vps. I have this script from the game website but i am not sure if its ok to just change the Ip address on it and use ip of my vps. Thanks

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE ^E_WARNING);

$web['connection'] = 'mssql';

$web['localhost'] = '127.0.0.1';

$web['dbhost'] = 'worldstr-41660c';

$web['database'] = 'RanUser';

$web['dbuser'] = 'resgame';

$web['dbpassword'] = 'res2gamedb';


require("includes/web.php");

?>"
```

Comment: First thing you need to know what OS you're webserver is running. Based on that you either need to check if the proper drivers are [installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9249748/446594). You also have to enable remote connections on the SQL server and make sure the port is not closed

Comment: Thanks, the webserver will be windows as well. Sql connection is already enabled with a secret port.

Comment: SQL server or MySQL ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72XCFF4YiOw) could help